# Running Multiple queries on threads with Java

Tags: multithreading

My java code connects to database and fetches data. The same is put in excel and forwarded to users. I have multiple queries running sequentially. I need to  run all in different threads, so that there is no wait for any query. The main concern is that some queries take long time, but some very short time. If all can be run on different threads, then we need not wait for each query processing.

Please suggest on this as to how this can done. Is it possible to have it done ??

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [ExecutorCompletionService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html).
You might want to use two separate `ExecutorCompletionService` instances, one for short running queries and the other for long time queries.